# Async middleware for Express

Tags: javascript, node.js

As we know, Express is not very good in handling async functions, in particular for the error handling.

I did define an asyncMiddleware as follows:

```
const asyncMiddleware = fn => (req, res, next) => {
  Promise.resolve(fn(req, res, next)).catch(next);
};
```

And then:

```
router.get('/', asyncMiddleware(myRouteHandler))
```

Is there a way to properly rewrite the middleware in order to make it usable directly by the Express router?

```
 router.use(asyncMiddleware)
```

Comment: There certainly is but I'd be interested in hearing more what it is you are trying to do because Express has it's own [error handling mechanism](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html).

Comment: There's no legit way. Express should be hacked to do that. Check express-ko as a reference.

Comment: @estus "hacked" is probably not the correct term, I'd say "enhanced" :)

Comment: @James Well, enhancing should be done in a hacky way because of how Express classes are implemented, they are mixins that cannot be easily extended.

Comment: @estus why do you think this can't be done with custom middleware? I've actually implemented this for certain routers where I know they will all use async code, and the app was already heavily embedded with Express so the idea of just switching to Koa or the like wasn't really an option.

Comment: @James A middleware can get an error that was passed to it by previous middleware with `next(err)`. In case previous middleware returns a rejected promise instead of passing it with `next`, it's ignored, this behaviour cannot be changed in a legit way. I'm not sure if we talk about the same thing, but to my understanding, the OP wants to do `app.use(makeExpressUnderstandPromises)` and then do `router.get('/', myRouteHandlerThatReturnsAPromise)` without wrapping it with `asyncMiddleware`, and that's impossible without patching Express.

Comment: "_A middleware can get an error that was passed to it by previous middleware_" - only if said middleware has the appropriate signature i.e. `(req, res, next, err) => { ... }` - so in scenarios where the OP has a Promise-based route handler having custom middleware to wrap `next` seems a reasonable solution to me. The OP then has either option - throw in the handler (and thus have it handled by `asyncMiddleware`) or return `next(err)` which is then handled by the built in error handler? I've implemented something similar without changing Express...

Answer (score 0):

Koa supports promises natively, it's expected that Express 5 will do this as well.

> Is there a way to properly rewrite the middleware in order to make it usable directly by the Express router?

There is no way. In order to do that, Express `app` and `router` (`express.Router` and `express.Route` classes) methods that use middlewares and route handlers should be monkey-patched to do what `asyncMiddleware` does.

Otherwise promise-based middlewares should be manually wrapped with a helper like `asyncMiddleware`.

Comment: "There is no way" - of course there is, it's whether you want to put what is effectively a plaster onto a framework when there is already frameworks out there (like Koa) that already do this.